# Mysql order by (where menu_name = child_name)

Tags: mysql

I have some mysql query to display menu. I want the menu ordered by parent and it's child. this is my base query :

```
select * from (
select a.menu_id, a.menu_name, a.menu_parent parent, a.menu_parent parent_id, a.menu_order 
from menu_backend a
where a.menu_parent = '0'

union all

select b.menu_id, concat('--',b.menu_name) menu_name, c.menu_name parent, b.menu_parent parent_id, b.menu_order
from menu_backend b
left join menu_backend c on c.menu_id = b.menu_parent
where b.menu_parent != '0'
) alias
```

and this is the result :

http://xomf.com/vgjgc

I want to order the child menu exactly to the parent, but i don't know how to do it.
Thanks

Comment: is this your current result or expect result?

Comment: hi @JaydipRakholiya thanks for reply, that is current result. I want to move the child menu which named with "--menu name" to the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't modify your base SQL a lot, how about this?

```
select *
  from (select a.menu_id,
               a.menu_name,
               a.menu_parent parent,
               a.menu_parent parent_id,
               a.menu_order,
               a.menu_id     sort_id
          from menu_backend a
         where a.menu_parent = '0'
        union all
        select b.menu_id,
               concat('--', b.menu_name) menu_name,
               c.menu_name parent,
               b.menu_parent parent_id,
               b.menu_order,
               b.menu_parent sort_id
          from menu_backend b
          left join menu_backend c
            on c.menu_id = b.menu_parent
         where b.menu_parent != '0') alias
 order by sort_id, parent_id, menu_order
```